# How to create a "male" variable in stata

Tags: regression, stata

My stata regression currently has the female variable, but I want to test whether gender matters on another variable or not. How would I go about creating the male variable? Or do I even need it? Will dropping the female variable work as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to create a "Male" variable. If "Female" is a binary variable, then Female = 1 describes females, and Female = 0 describes male.

Using that variable *is* examining the effect of gender.

The reason people tend to use gender variable names like Male or Female is they have a logical reading if the code book is lost/misplaced/deleted by an undergrad, whereas "Gender 0/1" can't be interpreted if you don't know what was originally Gender = 1 and Gender = 0.

Comment: Hey epigrad, that does make sense! So as I have it, female = 1. Does the effect of sat (SAT Scores) on colgpa (College GPA) differ by gender? How would I know?

Comment: @EmilioA The answer to that will depend on your data, but you're most likely looking at using some form of linear regression. That's likely best suited to being a separate question.

Comment: Will running the regression without the female variable at all test for male then? because I figured that if i type in "regress COLGPA x1 x2 x3 sat female" and then "regress COLGPA x1 x2 x3 sat", and compare the  two coefficients of SAT, this will tell me if gender matters... would that be correct?

Comment: My guess is no. I don't know stata commands specifically, but you want to to keep the female variable in. It is the coefficient of that variable in your regression model that will tell you whether or not gender impacts the association. As I said, that's an entirely separate question I'd suggest you post.

Comment: I see no Stata-specific issues here, but EpiGrad's advice is entirely sound. Emilio needs to keep a `Female` variable in his model to test for any gender effect. He should also do some reading on indicator (dummy) variables.

Comment: The only Stata-specific issues were the specific commands to be fed in.

Comment: Emilio's Stata code was all legal and he did not make clear any doubts about it; hence my conclusion that he is just asking how to analyse data.